# Create nested set model without top level item

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm creating a nested set model for a taxonomy database.  Basically, I've re-created the same type of setup that wordpress uses for taxonomy, however instead of using parent_id for the term_taxonomy, I'd like to implement a nested set model for taxonomies that are hierarchical.

The issue I'm finding is that terms aren't placed into the term_taxonomy table, until there is an actual term or category name.  However, with a nested set model, you need one entry to be that top level item.

Is it possible to do a nested set model, without having a top level? Instead you could have 5 top levels and subsets, etc.

Comment: You can certainly have as many top level items as you want.  Nested sets is about relating parents, children, grand children, great grand children and so forth to their ancestors.  There is nothing to say that there has to be a single root item in your hierarchy.  You can have as many roots as you need.